# Requesting Assistance with Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

A Quote record is linked to a Price Book record. The Quote Line record is the detail record of the Quote in a master-detail relationship. The Price Book Entry is the detail record of the Price Book in a master-detail relationship. The Quote Line is 1:1 to the Product. The Product is the master record to the Price Book Entry.

I want to test out an Apex trigger that would, on the Quote Line, look to the Product record, and knowing the Price Book on the Quote, fetch the correct Price Book Entry record and custom field and map it to the Quote Line.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
trigger SelectGPOFromPriceBookEntry on SBQQ__QuoteLine__c (before insert) {
    String gpo = [SELECT GPO__c FROM PricebookEntry LIMIT 1]; 
}
```

I need to join the Price Book ID of the Price Book Entry with the Price Book ID of the Quote within the SOQL query, right? 
How would I structure the SOQL query to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather advanced form of trigger, because you need to look up several values. Something like this:

```
trigger QuoteLineItem on QuoteLineItem (before insert) {
    // Multipart Key
    class MapKey {
        Id pricebookId, product2Id;
        // Constructor
        MapKey(Id pricebookId, Id product2Id) {
            this.pricebookId = pricebookId;
            this.product2Id = product2Id;
        }
        public override String toString() {
            return String.format(
                // ♪ Interpolation with quotes requires massive escaping ♪
                '(Pricebook2Id = \\\'{0}\\\' AND Product2Id = \\\'{1}\\\')',
                new String[] { pricebookId, product2Id }
            );
        }
        // Required to be used in a map correctly.
        public Boolean equals(Object o) {
            MapKey other = (MapKey)o;
            return other.pricebookId == pricebookId && other.product2Id == product2Id;
        }
        // Required to be used in a map correctly.
        public Integer hashCode() {
            return (''+pricebookId+product2Id).hashCode();
        }
    }

    // Get the quotes first-- we don't get them for free
    Map<Id, Quote> quotes = new Map<Id, Quote>();
    for(QuoteLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        quotes.put(record.QuoteId, null);
    }
    quotes.putAll([SELECT Pricebook2Id from Quote WHERE Id IN :quotes.keyset()]);
    // Prepare a map that matches on Pricebook2Id/Product2Id
    Map<MapKey, Id> entries = new Map<MapKey, Id>();
    for(QuoteLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        entries.put(new MapKey(quotes.get(record.QuoteId).Pricebook2Id, record.Product2Id), null);
    }
    // Build the WHERE clause
    String[] filters = new String[0];
    for(MapKey key: entries.keySet()) {
        filters.add(key+'');    // implicit toString() call
    }
    // Populate the map
    for(PricebookEntry record: Database.query('SELECT Product2Id, Pricebook2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE '+String.join(filters, ' OR '))) {
        entries.put(new MapKey(record.Pricebook2Id, record.Product2Id), record.Id);
    }
    // And finally update the original records
    for(QuoteLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        record.PricebookEntryId = entries.get(new MapKey(quotes.get(record.QuoteId).Pricebook2Id, record.Product2Id));
    }
}
```

Note that if you must *also* support multicurrency, your code is going to be a little bit more complex.

Edit: Also note that *real* quote line items work from the PricebookEntry, not the Product2Id/Pricebook2Id fields. This code, while it compiles, would probably crash.

Comment: OMG! I learnt so many features of Apex going through your code. Thanks for your time!